# Logging Framework for iOS?

Tags: ios, logging

Is there a logging framework for iOS that could aid developers in diagnosing app crashes?

Comment: do you mean logging in terms of debugging on your own test equipment or logging user activity when app is in production?

Comment: @dusker: For production as well as for debugging during development of the app.

Comment: Although this question is quite old but a good option right now is Forestry. In case anyone is still looking.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You may like:

- [Lumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack): stable and traditional

> *"It is similar in concept to other popular logging frameworks such as log4j, yet is designed specifically for Objective-C, and takes advantage of features such as multi-threading, grand central dispatch (if available), lockless atomic operations, and the dynamic nature of the Objective-C runtime."*

- [LibComponentLogging](https://github.com/aharren/LibComponentLogging-Core/): beautiful and hardcore, used by RestKit

> *"LibComponentLogging is a small logging library for Objective-C applications on Mac OS X and the iPhone OS which provides conditional logging based on log levels and log components. Additionally, different logging strategies can be used, e.g. writing log messages to a file or sending them to the system log, while using the same logging interface."*

- [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger): fancy with a dedicated visualization OS X App

> *"NSLogger is a high perfomance logging utility which displays traces emitted by client applications running on Mac OS X or iOS (iPhone OS). It replaces your usual NSLog()-based traces and provides powerful additions like display filtering, image and binary logging, traces buffering, timing information, etc."*

Comment: Also don't forget Apple's standard ASL library. With a few wrapper functions you can get very nice logging with multiple trace levels (debug, info, warning, error, ... etc.).

Answer (score 7):

I know this post is old but I'm looking for one as well. I found one called [Lumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack), though I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Does it provide encryption if one needs to store the log securely?

Answer (score 4):

I created a simple logging framework that might help.  I'd appreciate any feedback you have.  Hope it helps.

Link to [Project Page](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/snlog)

Answer (score 3):

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355802/whats-the-best-way-to-log-debug-info-in-an-iphone-app) seems to overlap. But the bottom line is:

`NSLog(@"message");`

or:

`printf("message");`

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different need: not only do I want to debug crashes, but I also need to debug other errors (NSError, NSException).

I tried all 3 packages mentioned in IlDan's answer. However, all of them require me to adopt a new way of logging, which may not be compatible with the libraries I depend on. For example, I intended to adopt NSLogger but RestKit, which is an important library in my project, uses LibComponentLogging.

So I ended up with writing a small pod (https://github.com/kennethjiang/Teleport-NSLog) for that. The mechanism is to redirect stderr (where NSLog + all these logging frameworks write messages to) to a backend HTTP server. Now I can debug my app running in user's device just as if it was running in my xcode. :)

Answer (score 0):

For basic logging use NSLog(@"your message here")
If you want more flexible logging look into [Lumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack). It can let you disable logging in production etc etc.