# How to access device log (not crash report) in Xcode organizer

Tags: ios, logging, xcode4.2, printf, device

Xcode (4.2) shows a log in the console view. The device logs view shows only crash logs. The console view contains NSLog output (as warnings?). I've never seen log events older than an hour or so. Where are all the older logs? How can i access NSLog output that was generated a week ago or so?

The answer to the question [what happens to NSLog info when running on a device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318342/what-happens-to-nslog-info-when-running-on-a-device) states that i should see NSLog output in device logs. Is this or is this not the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your NSLogs are not saved to disk, you will only see the recent ones in the console. If you want to store your logs you will need to do it yourself. This comment has some good options:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13761487/589224

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663754/is-nslog-stored-on-the-device-iphone-etc-if-so-where) says otherwise.